# serialize list of generic type

Tags: c#, generics, xml-serialization

I am writing an application for serialization of a generic List that holds any datatype.So I designed a base-DataType to fill the list with as follows:

```
public abstract class GenericObject<T> {
    public string key;
    public T value;

    public GenericObject() { }
    public GenericObject(string key, T value) : this() { 
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Furthermore there is a class `GenericList` which implements the `IXmlSerializable`-Interface to write a key-value pair as like this:

```
GenericObject<int> myInt = new GenericObject<int>("key", 3);
```

Which will produce the following XML:

```
<key>3</key>
```

The class-definition for the `GenericList` is more or less as follows:

```
public class GenericList<T> : IXmlSerializable {
    List<T> objects;
    // ...
}
```

So let´s assume we have a class `Person` that derives from `GenericObject<string>`(no matter how it looks like) and we want to fill the list with a couple of persons. The problem I have is defining a constraint on the generic type T of the `GenericList`-class so that only types are possible that derive from `GenericObject`. I already tried it by using `public class GenericList<T> : IXmlSerializable where T : GenericObject<object>` but that did not work because of the following compiler error:

```
Person' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'GenericList<T>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Person' to 'GenericObject<object>'
```

I also tried out leaving the where-clause empty, but then I have to check the type of `T` within the `GenericList` in order to get its key and value where I also failed with the following:

```
if (typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(GenericObject<object>)))
```

which will always return false as `T` is of type Person and not `GenericObject<object>`.

May anyone have some suggestion how I can fill my list with a person?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx). Since variant type parameters only can be declared in interfaces and delegates (not in class definitions), you also need to define an interface:

```
public interface IGenericObject<out T>
{
    string Key { get; }
    T Value { get; }
}

public abstract class GenericObject<T> : IGenericObject<T>
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }

    protected GenericObject() { }

    protected GenericObject(string key, T value)
        : this()
    {
        this.Key = key;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}

public class GenericList<TGenericObject> : IXmlSerializable
    where TGenericObject : IGenericObject<object>
{
    private readonly List<TGenericObject> _list = new List<TGenericObject>();

    public void Add(TGenericObject item)
    {
        _list.Add(item);
    }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public class Person : GenericObject<string>
{

}
```

Now you can do this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        Person somePerson = new Person();

        GenericList<IGenericObject<object>> listWithGenericsOfObject = new GenericList<IGenericObject<object>>();
        listWithGenericsOfObject.Add(somePerson);

        GenericList<IGenericObject<string>> listWithGenericsOfString = new GenericList<IGenericObject<string>>();
        listWithGenericsOfString.Add(somePerson);

        GenericList<Person> listWithGenericsOfPerson = new GenericList<Person>();
        listWithGenericsOfPerson.Add(somePerson);
    }
}
```

Now you don't need to check the type at runtime using IsAssignableFrom. However, in case you will need it, you should swap the types like this:

```
typeof(GenericObject<object>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))
```

Comment: Wow, really nice solution, although I do not exactly know why it works :D If I could I would give this answer 100 votes

Comment: To understand why it works, I think you need to read about variance (covariance in particular). The 'out'-keyword in the interface specifies that the type parameter is covariant.