# Saving a generic list

Tags: c#, generics

Is there a way to save a list to disk generically?  I tried data contract serializer, but it always generates an empty list.

```
    public static List<T> Load<T>() where T : class,new()
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<T>));

        string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + typeof(T).ToString() + ".xml");
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            return new List<T>();
        }
        else
        {
            using (var s = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
            {
                return serializer.ReadObject(s) as List<T>;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Save<T>(List<T> data) where T : class,new()
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<T>));

        Enumerate<T>(data);

        string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + typeof(T).ToString() + ".xml");
        using (var s = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(s, data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The duplicate had errors in the code.

Comment: @tekan that question doesn't appear to exist.

Comment: What does the `Enumerate(data)` method do? Does the compiler require `Enumerate<T>(data)` instead of `Enumerate(data)`?

Comment: @quillbreaker what is type of `T` you are trying to serialize? Does your code work with simple types, like string or int? Do you see generated file with data, or error occurs during serialization?

Comment: @AustinMullins When i posted it it existed... quillbreaker: Ok.

Comment: @quillbreaker you know you can press the edit button. Anyways. Lots of red flags are popping up for your code. `as` casting, could be hiding errors. `T` isn't included so I don't know if it is correctly attributed. `Enumerate<T>` not included in code listing. `where new()` is completely superfluous (and possibly even the `where class`). Are you even sure that the `return new List<T>()` code branch isn't running? You might not have permission to write to `App_Data`.

Comment: Do you care about how it is serialized? JSON, XML, binary?

Comment: possible duplicate of [serialize list of generic type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378084/serialize-list-of-generic-type)

Comment: I actually don't care about how it's serialized, as long as I can deserialize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use JavaScriptSerializer

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(thing);
```

JSON lists are generic.

UPDATE: Ass claimed by TimS Json.NET is better serializer so if adding 3rd party library is an option  [here is an article on how to do it.](http://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/c-dynamic-object-and-json-serialization-with-json-net/)

Comment: @TimS. Even the microsoft team agrees. All the new Open Source Microsoft stuff uses Json.Net.

Comment: I looked into Json.Net, and it is making lists of empty objects for me.

Comment: More detailed answer about this here, agreed JSON.net is desirable if available. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110724/serializing-a-list-to-json/9110986#9110986

Comment: I have resolved the list of empty objects issue and I'm currently using the JSON.net serializer.  I'll accept soon.

Answer (score 2):

What about a binary serializer

```
    public static void SerializeToBin(object obj, string filename)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filename));
        System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter bf = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            bf.Serialize(fs, obj);
        }
    }
    public static T DeSerializeFromBin<T>(string filename) where T : new()
    {
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            T ret = new T();
            System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter bf = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                ret = (T)bf.Deserialize(fs);
            }
            return ret;
        }
        else
            throw new FileNotFoundException(string.Format("file {0} does not exist", filename));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you're trying to do, the key might also be your class T, ensuring that it is decorated with the proper `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes. Here is a working example based on your code in question (however if you don't care to be able to utilize the persisted file outside of your code, you might find better performance in the binary serializer):

```
[DataContract]
public class Mydata
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Mydata> myData = new List<Mydata>();
        myData.Add(new Mydata() { Id = 1, Name = "Object 1" });
        myData.Add(new Mydata() { Id = 2, Name = "Object 2" });
        string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\" + typeof(Mydata).ToString() + ".xml";
        Save<Mydata>(myData, path);

        List<Mydata> myNewData = Load<Mydata>(path);
        Console.WriteLine(myNewData.Count);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static List<T> Load<T>(string filename) where T : class
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<T>));

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
        {
            return new List<T>();
        }
        else
        {
            using (var s = new System.IO.FileStream(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
            {
                return serializer.ReadObject(s) as List<T>;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Save<T>(List<T> list, string filename)
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<T>));

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (XmlDictionaryWriter writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(fs))
            {
                serializer.WriteObject(writer, list);
            }
        }
    }
}
```